# How forward Server port to Virtual Machine?

Tags: server, 20.04, kvm-virtualization, ufw

I'm trying redirect all my port 80 traffic to a virtual machine.

Server setup:

```
Main Server:
interfaces:
en0: ip 192.168.1.2
virbr0: ip 192.168.10.1

Virtual Machine:
interfaces
en0: ip 192.168.1.3
en1: ip 192.168.10.3

ips 192.168.1.X -> controlled by router
ips 192.168.10.X -> controlled by main server
```

I try that commands:

```
sudo ufw route allow to 192.168.1.3 port 80 from 0.0.0.0/0 port 80
```

To redirecct all incomming traffic on port 80 to VM by router

```
sudo ufw route allow in on en0 out on virbr0 to 192.168.10.3 port 80 from 192.168.1.0/24 port 80
```

To redirect all traffic in port 80 to VM by server

but nothing worked, main server refuse every connection (acessing 192.168.1.3 on browser works fine)

```
sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
OpenSSH                    ALLOW       Anywhere
3389                       ALLOW       Anywhere
OpenSSH (v6)               ALLOW       Anywhere     (v6)
3389 (v6)                  ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

192.168.1.3 80             ALLOW FWD   80
```

any idea why my redirect is not working

Comment: I think this: `from 0.0.0.0/32 port 80` should be this: `from 0.0.0.0/0`

Comment: i want redirect only port 80 incomming traffic

Comment: Understood, but the rule is only redirecting address 0.0.0.0 source port 80 destined for  192.168.1.3 destination port 80. What you want is any address any source port destined for 192.168.1.3 destination port 80.

Comment: wow, right, but the change does affect nothing